# Angular programming Practice

Tags: angularjs-directive

Angular Parent to Child

I want a angular code which have three component parent, child1, child 2. Parent message go to child1 and child1 message go to child2 and finally child2 message go to parent accordingly and every component has a button to click.

Comment: It's important to try solving the problem on your own first. If you encounter difficulties or get stuck, feel free to reach out for assistance, but remember that the learning process is most effective when you make the initial effort.